# yarn build failed on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I try to build js project that builds on Intel machines fine. But on Apple Silicon M1 I received this error. Adding this libraries to package.json didn't change anything.

```
⠴  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           17:09:42

These dependencies were not found:

* @/views/Offer/components/Documents.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Offer/Offer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
* @/views/Offer/components/OfferSeller.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Offer/Offer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
* @/views/Offer/components/OfferTop.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Offer/Offer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
* @/views/Offer/components/ParamsList.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Offer/Offer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
* @/views/Offer/components/PaymentTypes.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Offer/Offer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts

To install them, you can run: npm install --save @/views/Offer/components/Documents.vue @/views/Offer/components/OfferSeller.vue @/views/Offer/components/OfferTop.vue @/views/Offer/components/ParamsList.vue @/views/Offer/components/PaymentTypes.vue
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

`yarn build` runs `vue-cli-service build`.
`yarn build` or `npm run build` gives the same result.

Comment: Did you run the command it tells you to run?

Comment: Yes! This command fails. This is not correct hint. This command tries to find package.json in all pathes. But this is files & not directories.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a case-insensitive HFS+ macos file system. There were 2 directories in the `Offer` directory: `Components` and `components`. And the operating system saw them as one folder. Because of this, the build crashed.
After renaming `components` to `components2` build was successfuly finished.